# How to create a text list of all your tasks in Microsoft Outlook?

Tags: list, outlook, task

I have several hundred tasks in Microsoft Outlook.  I was hoping I could create a text list or excel list of all the TASKS in OUTLOOK.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't need any automation, try clicking into the task list, select all (Ctrl + A) then copying into Excel (Ctrl + V).  Worked on my short task list in Outlook.

Comment: WOW, that was perfect.  Thank you very much.